# QOpenGLWidget: cannot disable blending (Qt5.10)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I have an app written in Qt5.10 using QOpenGLWidget. I use raw OpenGL calls to draw on the widget.

If I have some viewport area that is drawn with alpha <1.0 this area is not drawn anew, but rather it looks like it's drawn over the previous state of the widget.
When I switch between different Windows apps, it's drawing over previous contents of the screen rendered by a different apps.

I don't change the default update behaviour of the widget.

I set the default SurfaceFormat as follows:

```
QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
surfaceFormat.setRedBufferSize(8);
surfaceFormat.setGreenBufferSize(8);
surfaceFormat.setBlueBufferSize(8);
surfaceFormat.setAlphaBufferSize(8);
surfaceFormat.setStencilBufferSize(8);
surfaceFormat.setDepthBufferSize(16);
surfaceFormat.setSamples(4);
surfaceFormat.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::RenderableType::OpenGL);
surfaceFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile::CompatibilityProfile);
surfaceFormat.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(surfaceFormat);
```

I was trying to add calls to glClear and glInvalidateFramebuffer in random places in the code, but it didn't seem to help.

What should I do to force redrawing of the widget?

Comment: When I switch from QOpenGLWidget to QOpenGLWindow wrapped in QWidget::createWindowContainer I have no such drawing artifacts.

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve].  Also note that [`QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsurfaceformat.html#setDefaultFormat) should, in general, be called *before* the construction of any `QApplication`.

Comment: For the record, I face the same problem. It seems to me that QT creates a drawbuffer for the window background with contents behind it and when we use glBlend, it is blending with this framebuffer as well. One possible solution is to use glBlendi, but this requires openGL 4.0. Have yet to test it though, so I am not going to post this as an answer yet.